# Getting onBeforeUnload to work with a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onbeforeunload

I am trying to get onbeforeunload to work with a set timer of sorts but I can't seem to get it to fire up when the return is in place. I am hoping it would work with a timer but for some reason the timer isn't working. Here is the code I am working  and thank you for your help in looking at it much appreciated.

```
var validNavigation = false;

function wireUpEvents() {
    var leave_message = 'Leaving the page';

    jQuery(
        function goodbye() {
            jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        jQuery(document.body).css('background-color', 'red');
                    }, 10000);
                },1);

            return leave_message;
        });
    }); 

    function leave() {
        if(!validNavigation) {
            killSession();
        }
    }

    //set event handlers for the onbeforeunload and onunloan events
    window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;

    window.onunload=leave;
}

// Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    wireUpEvents();
});
```

Comment: Please format you code properly when posting a question, it makes much easier to understand what it is saying. It will also help your self, any decent code editor will have an `indent` or `format` functionality that will do the work for you. For SO use spaces instead of tabs, and prepend 4 spaces to each line to make the code block display as code.

Comment: Sorry its always complicated to me posting code, Don't think i will ever really quiet get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onBeforeUnload` doesn't work with `setTimeout`.  After `onBeforeUnload` executes, `onUnload` will be triggered and the page will change.  This happens before the `setTimeout` callback is called.

Comment: Thanks @John for the answer. Do you know any way if I need to execute a method after particular time period when onbeforeunload gets triggered?

Comment: @AdarshKumar The only way to prevent the page from exiting after the user attempts to leave is by putting synchronous code in the onbeforeunload/onunload handler.  You technically could put a loop that executes until a certain amount of time has passed, but that will be inefficient and block the UI.

Comment: Of if there're any Synchronous Ajax calls

Comment: @Nayeem: Synchronous Ajax calls fall under the blanket of "synchronous code" that I mention above.

Answer (score 3):

@Jonh Kurlak is right, onbeforeunload doenst work with timeout to protect the browser user from being scammed.

But there is something you can do!!!

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

You can make this for loop printing to console to delay the unload of the page, the higher the number of iterations it as to loop through the longer it waits.